# Bootstrap datetimepicker / date picker not displaying calendar. Cannot pick a date

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to get bootstrap datetimepicker to work in conjunction with Datatables so that it filters the datatable when a date is picked. Problem is, it just shows up as an input bar on my page, there is no calendar or calendar symbol. It sounds like a CDN/library reference issue but I've double checked and seem to have them all loaded:

. Jquery
. moment.js
. Bootstrap
. bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
. bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css

I've made sure Moment is loaded before bootstrap and jquery. I believe that is all the references I need?Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='from'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='to'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
                $('#from').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
                    extraFormats: ['DD MM YYYY', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 
'DD/MM/YYYY', 'DD MMM YYYY', 'DD.MMM.YYYY', 'DD/MMM/YYYY', 'DD MMMM YYYY', 
'DD.MMMM.YYYY', 'DD/MMMM/YYYY']
                }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
                    UpdateDataCount();
                });

                $('#to').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
                    extraFormats: ['DD MM YYYY', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 
'DD/MM/YYYY', 'DD MMM YYYY', 'DD.MMM.YYYY', 'DD/MMM/YYYY', 'DD MMMM YYYY', 
'DD.MMMM.YYYY', 'DD/MMMM/YYYY']
                }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
                    UpdateDataCount();
                });
            });

UpdateDataCount: function () {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
            function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                var from = $('#from').datetimepicker("getDate");
                var to = $('#to').datetimepicker("getDate");

                //data being searched
                var startDate = new Date(data[2]);

                //if true show row/ if not, don't
                if (from == null && to == null) { return true; }
                if (from == null && startDate <= to) { return true; }
                if (to == null && startDate >= from) { return true; }
                if (startDate <= to && startDate >= from) { return true; }
                return false;
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, datetimepicker is not compatible with bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to see what your console is doing but I don't think you want to be repeatedly pushing a function, rather invoking it on change...

I got it working and there were issues with comparing moment Dates with vanilla Dates:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var from = null;
var to = null;

$('#from').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
    extraFormats: ['DD MM YYYY', 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        'DD/MM/YYYY', 'DD MMM YYYY', 'DD.MMM.YYYY', 'DD/MMM/YYYY', 'DD MMMM YYYY',
        'DD.MMMM.YYYY', 'DD/MMMM/YYYY'
    ]
}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
    from = e.date;
    table.draw();
});

$('#to').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
    extraFormats: ['DD MM YYYY', 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        'DD/MM/YYYY', 'DD MMM YYYY', 'DD.MMM.YYYY', 'DD/MMM/YYYY', 'DD MMMM YYYY',
        'DD.MMMM.YYYY', 'DD/MMMM/YYYY'
    ]
}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
    to = e.date;
    table.draw();
});

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        //data being searched
        var startDate = moment(data[2], "DD/MM/YYYY");
        if (!from && !to) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!from && startDate.isSameOrBefore(to, "day")) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!to && startDate.isSameOrAfter(from, "day")) {
            return true;
        }
        if (startDate.isSameOrBefore(to, "day") && startDate.isSameOrAfter(from, "day")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lxdjnso4/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I still have the same problem, but you solved an issue I would have encountered at some point or another anyway. The little calendar icon isn't showing up so I can't select a date. It's just a blank box.

Comment: Figured out what my issue is. I am using bootstrap 4, whereas datetimepicker uses bootstrap 3. Newb mistake, but you live and learn!